# Как установить htmlcxx под Qt

Tags: qt, htmlcxx

Как установить эту библиотеку под Qt, не могу никак разобраться. у меня Windows 10 а там все инструкции под Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/) же всё понятно описано.

- Скачиваете последнюю версию (ссылка там же в наличии)
- Распаковываете архив
- Собираете проект в Visual Studio
- Для использования: в pro-файле заполняете соответствующим образом секции INCLUDEPATH и LIBS
- ...
- PROFIT

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен только HTML парсер, берете допилинную немного мою версию, там всего три файла, добавляете в проект и используете.
А здесь примеры https://github.com/Ruzzz/htmlcxx/blob/master/test/test.cpp